Brownish dry semicircles on colocasia esculenta leaf edges (taro)
This taro plant was rooted in water, then placed in a 3 inch pot. When roots filled up the pot, I repotted it in a 4.5 inch pot. After this, these semicircular dry brown edge marks appeared. The plant is in a bright area and receives 15~20 minutes of direct sun in the morning, otherwise it is bright and indirect (outdoor balcony). Fertilised twice with diluted balanced npk and seaweed.
What is the problem? Overfertilisation or water issues or dry weather or the 20 min direct sun or the repotting?
